# Can I run p2pool with a thin bitcoin client?

Tags: bitcoind, blockchain, mining-pools, p2pool, thin-clients

Everytime I restart my mining machine due to heat, I have to wait the following sequence to mine at p2pool:

```
bitcoind -> download blockchain & rescan -> p2pool -> download shares -> start mining
```

It took me about 10~20 minutes.

Can I substitute bitcoind with thin client (without having to download blockchain)?

*PS1. I know I can connect a remote bitcoind, but I am thinking the possibility of a thin client on a local machine.

*PS2. Mining at public p2pool node is **out of consideration**.*

Comment: You might consider Eligius, which offers decentralized mining without the requirement of a local bitcoind (you only need it if you want to do extra verification yourself). http://eligius.st

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. P2Pool, unlike a normal pool, requires you to verify incoming transactions, and you can't do this without having all of the unspent transactions in the block chain.